# Isolated "Logging" Tables On DB - A Good Practice?

Tags: relational-database

I have to meet the requirement to log on a database all the requests made by my application to an external WCF service. I was suggested to create a kind of a "log table" on my application's support database, isolated from all the other tables, where the logs of this activity could go. However, I wonder if this is really a good practice, i.e., to keep an isolated "logging" table on a database which is supposed to be *relational*. What would you recommend in this case?

Comment: I don't understand why you think a log table is somehow anti-relational.

Comment: Just because of the fact it is not connected to any other table, but nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not? After all relational databases operate on matematical set theory which is not relational at all, it is just that when the standards were designed we added a special type that represents a foreign key.

Special types were also made to make it easier and more efficient to store dates, but that doesn't mean a database is designed badly if a table has no rowes with dates in them.

If your log statements genuently don't have any relations, then the database table in which they are stored shouldn't have either.